# Adding an image overlay to a video using C# and ffmpeg.exe

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg

I'm working on a project where I need to add an image overlay to a video using C# and ffmpeg.exe. I want to place the image at a specific position on the video and make sure it remains visible throughout the entire duration of the video. Can someone guide me on how to achieve this using the ffmpeg library in conjunction with C#?

I've looked into the documentation, but I couldn't find a straightforward example that demonstrates how to accomplish this task programmatically. Specifically, I'm interested in:

1. How to specify the position and size of the image overlay on the video.
2. How to ensure the image stays visible throughout the duration of the video, even if the video has varying resolutions or aspect ratios.
3. How to execute the ffmpeg command from C# code and capture any potential error messages or status updates.
   If anyone has experience with using C# and ffmpeg.exe to add image overlays to videos, your insights and code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Edit:
Here is my code:

```
        private async void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "ffmpeg.exe",
                Arguments = $"-f lavfi -i nullsrc -t 1 -s {pictureBox2.Width}x{pictureBox2.Height} -r 30 -c:v libx264 {"file.mp4"}",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };

            using (Process process = new Process())
            {
                process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                process.Start();
                process.WaitForExit();
            }
            render = true;
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(1, 1);
                    pictureBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
                    {
                        bmp = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image.Clone();
                    }));
                    while (bmp == pictureBox1.Image)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(10);
                    }
                    bmp.Save($"a.jpg");
                    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                    {
                        FileName = "ffmpeg.exe",
                        Arguments = $"-i file.mp4 -i a.jpg -filter_complex \"[0:v][1:v] overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0,20)'\" -pix_fmt yuv1080p -c:a copy file.mp4",
                        UseShellExecute = false,
                        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                        RedirectStandardError = true,
                        CreateNoWindow = true
                    };

                    using (Process process = new Process())
                    {
                        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                        process.Start();
                        process.WaitForExit();
                    }
                }
            });
            File.Delete("a.jpg");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var process = new Process())
    {
        process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("ffmpeg.exe")
        {
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            Arguments = "-i input.mp4 -i image.jpg -filter_complex \"[0:v][1:v] overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0,20)'\" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output.mp4"
        };

        process.Start();
    }
```

I got the answer from [here](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/12111) and translated it to C#.

That's the explanation:

> overlay=25:25 means we want to position the image 25px to the right
> and 25px down, originating from the top left corner (0:0).
>
> enable='between(t,0,20)' means we want the image to show between
> second 0 and 20.
>
> [0:v][1:v] means that we want the first video file we import with -i,
> in our case input.mp4 or how ffmpeg sees it, video input file number
> 0, to be under video input file 1, in our case image.png. :v just
> means we want the video track from these file sources. [0:a] would
> mean we want the first imported audio track. Which would also come
> from input.mp4 but would point to the audio track instead of the video
> track in the mp4 file.
>
> If you want a certain image quality/settings and not the settings
> ffmpeg chooses, add the image and or audio encoding options you want
> to use. The default video encoder will be x264. Check the H.264
> encoding guide for possible settings.
>
> The -acodec copy / -c:a copy that you have in your command f.e. would
> simply re-use the audio from the source file. Though you can't do that
> with the video of course (in this case), that has to be transcoded
> because we are creating a new video source.
>
> If you want to transcode audio, remove the -c:a copy part. You may
> have to explicitly specify an encoder, e.g. -c:a aac -strict
> experimental. See the AAC encoding guide for more info.

Comment: Is this without re encoding? Btw it's not working.

Comment: I tested it and it worked for me

Comment: What happens when you use it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76691466/ffmpeg-combining-video-with-transparent-image-results-in-0-byte-output?noredirect=1#comment135210871_76691466