# FFmpeg: Combining Video with Transparent Image Results in 0-Byte Output

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to combine a video with a transparent image using FFmpeg in my C# application. However, I'm encountering an issue where the resulting output video is consistently 0 bytes in size. I have reviewed the code and made several attempts to troubleshoot the problem, but I haven't been able to find a solution.

Here is the relevant code snippet I am using:

```
private async void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ffmpegPath = "ffmpeg.exe"; // Path to the FFmpeg executable
    string videoPath = "input.mp4"; // Path to the input video
    string imagePath = "image.png"; // Path to the transparent image
    string outputPath = "output.mp4"; // Path for the output video

    // Build the FFmpeg command with the image information
    string command = $"-i \"{videoPath}\" -loop 1 -t 5 -i \"{imagePath}\" -filter_complex \"[1:v]colorkey=0x000000:0.1:0.1[fg];[0:v][fg]overlay[outv]\" -map \"[outv]\" -map 0:a? -c:a copy \"{outputPath}\"";

    // Execute the FFmpeg command
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = ffmpegPath,
        Arguments = command,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    };

    using (Process process = new Process())
    {
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

I have confirmed that the input video and transparent image files are valid and located in the correct paths. The code runs without any exceptions, but the resulting output video is always 0 bytes in size.

I have also tried different approaches, such as adjusting the alpha channel blending and preprocessing the image to ensure the transparent areas are fully opaque. However, none of these attempts have resolved the issue.

Is there anything I might be missing or any additional steps I should take to ensure that the resulting video is generated correctly with the transparent image properly overlayed?

Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Add `-report` to the command and rerun. Share the report.

Comment: It created three text files but the video file is still 0 byte.